# Use dash in the variable name in yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I was trying to run API Gateway locally on my Mac with sam and template.yaml. However, I got this error `ValueError: malformed url rule: '/v10/<device-name>'`  Here is my my code in template.yaml:

```
  GetListFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/lambda/
      Handler: getList.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        GetList:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /v10/{device-name}/
            Method: get
```

Is there a way to use "-" in the variable name? If not, is there a workaround? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396704/13126651 check this

Comment: Hi @JatinMehrotra! I still got the error `ValueError: malformed url rule: '/v10/<<vars["device-name"]>>` with `Path: /v10/{{vars["device-name"]}}`